# Adding two alists by values in elisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, associative-array

I have two lists of dotted-pairs of the form:

```
(((key1 . value1) . 5)
 ((key2 . value2) . 7))

(((key2 . value2) . 3)
 ((key3 . value3) . 9))
```

i want the result to be an association list:

```
(((key1 . value1) . 5)
 ((key2 . value2) . 10)
 ((key3 . value3) . 9))
```

How do i add two association lists by values in emacs lisp? In other words, if two alists have the same key, then values for that key should be added together in resulting alist.

The most probable answer for this is some elisp snippet, but i would also prefer a nifty emacs macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using the CL module (written with readability rather than efficiency in mind):

```
(require 'cl)

(defun merge-alists (function default alist1 alist2)
  (flet ((keys (alist) (mapcar #'car alist))
         (lookup (key alist) (or (cdr (assoc key alist)) default)))
    (loop with keys = (union (keys alist1) (keys alist2) :test 'equal)
          for k in keys collect
          (cons k (funcall function (lookup k alist1) (lookup k alist2))))))
```

You can use it like this:

```
elisp> (merge-alists '+ 0 '((foo . 1) (bar . 2)) '((foo . 11) (baz . 22)))
((baz . 22)
 (foo . 12)
 (bar . 2))

elisp> (merge-alists '* 1 '((foo . 1) (bar . 2)) '((foo . 11) (baz . 22)))
((baz . 22)
 (foo . 11)
 (bar . 2))

elisp> (merge-alists 'append '() '((foo a b) (bar c)) '((foo d e) (baz f g)))
((baz f g)
 (foo a b d e)
 (bar c))

elisp> (setq my-alist1 '(((key1 . value1) . 5) ((key2 . value2) . 7)))
(((key1 . value1) . 5)
 ((key2 . value2) . 7))

elisp> (setq my-alist2 '(((key2 . value2) . 3) ((key3 . value3) . 9)))
(((key2 . value2) . 3)
 ((key3 . value3) . 9))

elisp> (merge-alists '+ 0 my-alist1 my-alist2)
(((key3 . value3) . 9)
 ((key1 . value1) . 5)
 ((key2 . value2) . 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like:

```
(defun merge-alists (a1 a2)
   (let ((ac (copy-alist a1)))
      (dolist (x a2)
         (when (null (assoc (car x) ac))
        (add-to-list 'ac x)))
      ac))
```

it will return copy of first list with data added from second list...

But if you'll use simple `append` function, then duplicates won't be found anyway, as functions usually return first found value, not all that exist.

Update: sorry, incorrectly read question, another answers do it correctly, and in more general way... Although, here is my variant of this function, without using CL package:

```
(defun merge-alists (a1 a2)
  (let ((ac (copy-alist a1)))
    (dolist (x a2)
      (let ((r (assoc (car x) ac)))
    (if (null r)
      (add-to-list 'ac x)
      (setf (cdr r) (+ (cdr x) (cdr r))))))
    ac))
```

P.S. in your example, parentheses are unbalanced :-)